# Haskell difference lists and point free function

Tags: haskell, pointfree

I was researching difference lists and found the `DList` type

```
newtype DList a = DL { unDL :: [a] -> [a] }
```

and the function

```
dlToList :: DList a -> [a]
dlToList = ($[]) . unDL
```

I am wondering what is the non point free version of the function and what does `($[])` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step in seeing into a point-free definition of a function is to revert the η-reduction:

```
dlToList = ($[]) . unDL
dlToList dl = (($[]) . unDL) dl
```

Then you start applying to the composition-chain, right-to-left:

```
dlToList dl = ($[]) (unDL dl)
```

You could then unpack the operator section<sup>†</sup>

```
dlToList dl = unDL dl $ []
```

However, keeping the `($[])` as it is actually makes sense, because this is the essential converter between difference lists and ordinary lists: it takes a `[a]->[a]`-prepender-function and applies it to the terminator `[]`, resulting in a concrete list.

---

<sup>†</sup>
<sub>We could simplify that further:</sub>

```
dlToList dl = unDL dl []
```

which, incidentally, could be made point-free again in a shorter manner:

```
dlToList = (`unDL`[])
```

Comment: Also can you explain me how does this works?  `emptyDL :: DList a`
 `emptyDL = DL id`

Comment: The empty difference list is that list-prepending funcion which, when passed the (empty) terminator list, will just give that same list as the result.

Comment: But if we look at the types, `DL :: ([a] -> [a]) -> DList a` and `id :: a -> a`

Comment: Note that these polymorphic signatures are shorthand for _universally-quantified types_, i.e. really it should be `DL :: ∀a. ([a] -> [a]) -> DList a` and `id :: ∀a. a -> a`. Hence I might also write it as `id :: ∀b. b -> b`. And for any given type `A`, I can then substitute `b ~ [A]`. Got it?

Comment: This is clear now. I wasn't aware I can substitute `a ~ [A]. Thanks for that.